# Why is the open quotient of a second-countable space second-countable?

Tags: general-topology

I know that there are other posts on this topic, but they didn't help me.

So let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a second-countable topological space and $\pi:X\to X/\sim$ an open quotient map.

Let $B=(B_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a countable basis for $X$. I've read that now $(\pi(B_i))_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a basis for $X/\sim$. First of all the sets $\pi(B_i)$ are open, but lets take $O\in\mathcal{T}/\sim$, then $\pi^{-1}(O)\in\mathcal{T}$ and thus $\pi^{-1}(O)=\bigcup_{i\in I} B_i$ where $|I|\le |\mathbb{N}|$. Now the only obvious choice for $O$ would be $O=\bigcup_{i\in I}\pi(B_i)$, but I can't show the equality.
Is there another choice for the representation of $O$? I wonder, if the quotient topology may be able to make the basis too "coarse".

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to write $\pi^{-1}(x)\in B_i$. $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is a subset of $X$, not an element.

Comment: @Thorgott You are right, I will edit my post.

Comment: I dk what is meant by "open quotient map". The usual def'n of a quotient map is that the topology on $X/\sim$ is the strongest topology such that $\pi$ is continuous. Under this def'n $\pi$ maps open sets to open sets. But if $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual topology, and if  $x\sim y\iff (x=y\lor \{x,y\}\subset \Bbb Z)$ then $\Bbb R / \sim$ is not 1st-countable .

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Quotient maps in general are not open. E.g. the usual quotient map $[0,1]\rightarrow S^1$ does not map open sets of the form $[0,t)$ with $t<1$ to open sets in $S^1$. Similarly, in your example, e.g. an open ball of radius $1$ about $0$ does not get mapped to an open set in the quotient (its preimage is the union of that ball and $\mathbb{Z}$, which is not open in $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @Thorgott . Right . I always have difficulty with quotient maps.